# How can I make the 'aria-expanded' value back to 'false' when I move to the next element?

Tags: html, jquery, wai-aria

I have 2 dropdown button in my menu for which I added the 'aria-expanded'=false default value. There are also the 'up' and 'down' classes that are added to the buttons when a button is expanded or closed.  When I click on the first button to expand it, the 'aria-expanded' value turns 'true' and the 'up' class is added. Then I click on the second button and the 'aria-expanded' value for the 2nd button turns 'true' and class='up' is added. But here starts the problem. Even if the first button dropdown closed when I clicked on the 2nd button, and the 'down' class was added, the 'aria-expanded' value for the 1st button remains 'true'. It doesn't change back to 'false'.
[buttons][1]

Here is the jQuery code:

```
function initMenuDrowpDownHandlers() {
        $('.cfs_dropdown').parent().children('button').off('click.cfs_dropdown');
        $('.cfs_dropdown').parent().children('button').on('click.cfs_dropdown', function(e) {
            var lnk = $(this);
            console.log(lnk);
            if (lnk.hasClass('up')) {
                lnk.removeClass('up').addClass('down');
                lnk.attr("aria-expanded","false");
            } else {
                $('.cfs_dropdown').parent().children('button').removeClass('up').addClass('down');
                lnk.removeClass('down').addClass('up');
                lnk.attr("aria-expanded","true");
                $(document).on('click.cfs_drop', function (e) {
                    if ($(e.target).hasClass('disabled') || ($(e.target).parents('.cfs_dropdown')[0] && !$(e.target).is('button'))) return;
                    lnk.removeClass('up').addClass('down');
                    lnk.attr("aria-expanded","false");
                    $(document).off('click.cfs_drop');
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
```

I will appreciate any advice. Thank you.

Comment: How are you currently closing the dropdown menu when the user selects an option? This function would need to set `aria-expanded=false` as well, wouldn’t it. So you’d have one function to close the menu, which then is called for different events, like selecting an option, on `focusout`, on press of the Escape key.

Answer (score 0):

Try use [`blur` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event)

```js
yoursButton.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  yoursButton.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
});
```

Comment: That’s a good first step, but in a dropdown, options in the listbox need to be focused as well, which will blur the button. You wouldn’t want the attribute to be set in this case.